# Wrap relative positioned div around image

Tags: html, css

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-top: 100px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            bla
        </td>

        <td align="center">

            <div id="thisone" style="display: flex; position: relative; background-color: blue;">
                
                <div style="position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 100%; margin-top: -30px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; background-color: red;">
                    up
                </div>


                <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 20px; margin-left: -30px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; background-color: red;">
                    left
                </div>

                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1T1iFeN.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh;">
            </div>                  
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            bla
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I make the div `thisone` wrap around the image? I would also accept alternative to `relative` as long as the div with `up` inside is above the image and has the same width and `left` is left to the image and has the same height.

Comment: This does not answer your question..by why are you using `table`? This does not appear to be tabulator data, but rather a layout.

Comment: I minimised it for this question, there are hundreds of tr's created with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with additional div with inline-block around the relative div:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; margin-top: 100px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            bla
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <div  style="display: flex; position: relative; background-color: blue;">
                    
                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 20px; width: 100%; margin-top: -30px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; background-color: red;">
                        up
                    </div>


                    <div style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 20px; margin-left: -30px; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between; background-color: red;">
                        left
                    </div>

                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1T1iFeN.jpg" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100vh;">
                </div>  
            </div>
        </td>

        <td align="center">
            bla
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>
```